# Where does Toad's slime power come from?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Where does Toad's ability to spit thick, instantly hardening, suffocating slime come from, you know that slime he used on Jean Grey in the first Bryan Singer X-Men film? I've seen it in some of the X-Men shows and comics, but this was after the Ray Park character was introduced.

Comment: To clarrify ... you are asking what is the origin of Toad's slime or what is its power? I'm not seeing a defined question here.

Comment: Origin. Makes me wonder, do any real toads sling slime like that?

Comment: That said, Xmen evolution Toad also had the spitting. That show premiered in 2000 just ahead of Xmen the movie. So it's atleast that old.

Comment: Toads are (historically) supposed to spit poison to incapacitate their prey. It's actually a myth.

Comment: To cde- I realize about the show; however, this show aired 4 months AFTER the film. Also, to Paulster2, I am looking for the origin of the slime.

Comment: Poking around, I haven't found any commentary by the director, or by Ray Park, on the change in powers.

Comment: I know that it was originally scripted in an early draft of the film (which involved Pyro, Blob, & Beast before budget cuts) as Toad surprising Jean and licking her face, causing the slime to transfer from his tongue to her face. This occurs in the novelization of the film as well, but no word on where it changed to a spit attack with no surprise factor.

Comment: Did a bit more poking around. Found a very early script where Toad spit, and I quote, 'thick, black spittle' at Warren Worthington III, covering his face; however this COULD be coincidence since the black spittle burns Angel and the green slime cuts off Jean's oxygen.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, the first Bryan Singer X-Men movie is the first instance of Toad having this power.  Previously, he had only displayed the powers of agility, wall-gripping, and an extended, flexible tongue.

I cannot speak to why it was decided Toad should gain this power, but it did serve as an effective plot point - it helped split up the heroes so that there could be moments for each one to shine and character development (such as it was).  It also helped set up for Storm's line about toads and lightning (which I can only imaging was supposed to sound much cooler than it did).

Following the movie, this power proved popular enough that it was incorporated into other media.  It appeared in the X-Men Evolution TV show (which used many designs/influences from the Singer films) and eventually migrated to the comics as well.

Answer (score 1):

Toad gained the power to spit the resin after tinkering with his own genetic makeup using the Stranger's technology.

Source: http://marvel.com/universe/Toad

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the old X-Men Animated Show, there is an episode in where Toad actually creates slime from his hands and can throw it, but also the slime has a side effect, that it can put people in suspended animation, as the slime has similar effects as curare.