# Who was the first person to be slimed by Toad?

Tags: marvel, x-men, toads-spit

Many people have fallen victim of (read: been awarded with) [Toad's slime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toad_(comics)#Powers_and_abilities). However there needs to have been a first: **Who was the first being to be slimed by Toad?**

---

<sup>Yes, this is a real question. Toad's spit/slime is infamous and has [even become a meme on this very site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6699/21267), however I'm interested to know who the first recipient of it was.</sup>

Comment: We have [toads-spit] and people don't want [knight-bus]? Lol

Comment: chronologically by publication, or in his life?

Comment: @phantom42 Order of publication, then by his life, if that makes sense to do it that way.

Comment: First appearance was *The X-Men #4 (1964)*. I'm sure he slimed someone then. If anyone has a Marvel account, they can look at that issue.

Comment: Actually, you'd be wrong, @jonah. See [Toad's slime power](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/91456/5184). There is no instance of him having a slime ability in any continuity before 2000.

Comment: That's interesting... it looks like his power-up was in an alternate universe set of comics and then people just sort of moved it over to the main universe as if it had always been that way.

Comment: Define "slime" - does resin count as slime? (cf [this panel of _X-Force_ #7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJJE9.png))

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, it was Scott Summers/Cyclops on the Fox Kids! TV show X-Men: The Animated Series, in Season 3, episode 25, entitled "Secrets, Not Long Buried". Cyclops travels to a lone island and at one point is ambushed by Toad, who is using his powers to secrete a sticky slime from his hands to trap intruders in a make-shift cocoon. The only other three I am aware of are Jean Grey in the first X-Men movie, a news-reporter at a Bayville High soccer game in an episode of X-Men: Evolution, and the Old Man Logan version of Wolverine in the Old Man Logan storyline.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! This a good first answer. Do you have any screen shots or official episode synopsis that might help confirm your reasoning?